# How to show and play captured photos and videos,Audios in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi i am beginner in Ios and in my project i have given facility for users capturing photos and videos and Audios from camera and i am storing their "paths" in array lists and i am displays them in one table-list so for everything is ok

But here my main requirement is when i click table-list rows then if there is image file it must be shows or if there is video it must be play audio also have to play as like videos for this i have written some code here photos and videos are playing fine but audio files giving problem what did i do here wrong?

### my code:-

```
 #import "ViewController2.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController2 ()
{
    NSMutableArray * arr_mediaType;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImage *snap;
    NSData *data1;
    NSMutableArray * arr_media;

    MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer;
    UIImageView *dot;
    AVAudioRecorder * _audioRecorder;
    AVAudioPlayer * player;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize maintablelist;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    arr_mediaType = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr_media = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    maintablelist.delegate = self;
    maintablelist.dataSource = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,      nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)takeVideo:(id)sender {

    NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"] || [model isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Angry!!!" message:@"No Camera found!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)takeAudio:(id)sender {

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
    NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];  // to get unique name

    NSString *soundfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%@.m4a",fileName];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundfile];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];


    NSLog(@"FilePath:%@",soundFileURL);

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    NSError *error = nil;

    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                        error:nil];

    _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                      initWithURL:soundFileURL
                      settings:recordSetting
                      error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"ok");
        [arr_media addObject:soundFilePath];
        [_audioRecorder record];
        [maintablelist reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

        [mediaType  isEqual: @"Photos"];

        [arr_mediaType addObject:@"Photos"];

        snap = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pic-%@.png", fileName]];

        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(snap, 1.0);
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        NSLog(@"So finally path is%@",filePath);

        [arr_media addObject:filePath];

        [maintablelist reloadData];

    }

    else {

        [mediaType  isEqual: @"Videos"];
        [arr_mediaType addObject:@"Video"];

        NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

        NSLog(@"videoURL --->>> %@",videoURL);

        NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];

        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"video%@.mov", fileName]];

        BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];

        [arr_media addObject:filePath];

        NSLog(@"videoURLPath --->>> %@",filePath);

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        [maintablelist reloadData];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arr_mediaType.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cells=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cells];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([[arr_mediaType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Photos"]) {

        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
        dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,320,240,128)];
        dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.view addSubview:dot];
    }
    else if([[arr_mediaType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Videos"])
    {
        [dot removeFromSuperview];

        NSURL*theurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 320, 240, 128)];
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *filePath = [arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have modified your piece of code. First of all, there is no need of different arrays to store images and videos. You can access it from one. Simillarly, there is no need of storing media types in two different arrays. You can do it by one array.

Moreover, to save images and videos to document directory, you need to write those file to specific path. You will then be able to access them.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray * arr_mediaType;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
    UIImage *snap;
    NSData *data1;
    NSMutableArray * arr_media;

    MPMoviePlayerController * moviePlayer;
    UIImageView *dot;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tbl;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    arr_mediaType = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    arr_media = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    tbl.delegate = self;
    tbl.dataSource = self;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {



    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage,      nil];

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];

}

- (IBAction)takeVideo:(id)sender {


    NSString *model = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];

    if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"] || [model isEqualToString:@"iPad Simulator"])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Angry!!!" message:@"No Camera found!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    else
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.videoMaximumDuration = 10;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie,      nil];
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}

-(IBAction)takeAudio
{
        NSArray *dirPaths;
        NSString *docsDir;

        dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                       NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        docsDir = dirPaths[0];
        NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];  // to get unique name

        NSString *soundfile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%@.m4a",fileName];

        NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                                   stringByAppendingPathComponent:soundfile];

        NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];


        NSLog(@"FilePath:%@",soundFileURL);

        NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        NSError *error = nil;

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                            error:nil];

        _audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                          initWithURL:soundFileURL
                          settings:recordSettings
                          error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            [arr_media addObject:soundFilePath];
            [_audioRecorder record];
        }
}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){

        [mediaType  isEqual: @"Photos"];

        [arr_mediaType addObject:@"Photos"];

        snap = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
        NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pic-%@.png", fileName]];

        NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(snap, 1.0);
        [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];



        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



        //UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

//        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//        
//        NSString *Dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pic-%lf.png", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
//        
//        //this path if you want save reference path in sqlite
//        NSString *pngPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",Dir,fileName];
//        
      NSLog(@"So finally path is%@",filePath);

        [arr_media addObject:filePath];

        [tbl reloadData];


    }

    else {

       [mediaType  isEqual: @"Videos"];
    [arr_mediaType addObject:@"Video"];

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSLog(@"videoURL --->>> %@",videoURL);

    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];

    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"video%@.mov", fileName]];

    BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];

    [arr_media addObject:filePath];

    NSLog(@"videoURLPath --->>> %@",filePath);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [tbl reloadData];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arr_mediaType.count;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *cells=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cells];
    }


        cell.textLabel.text = [arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([[arr_mediaType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Photos"]) {

        [moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
        dot =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40,320,240,128)];
        dot.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.view addSubview:dot];
    }
    else if([[arr_mediaType objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Videos"])
    {
        [dot removeFromSuperview];
        //        NSString*thePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"MOV"];
    NSURL*theurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theurl];
        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 320, 240, 128)];
        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
        [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *filePath = [arr_media objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSData *soundData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:soundData error:nil];
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player play];
    }

@end
```

Comment: Glad to help you mate!!

Comment: see my updated code how to play audios when we tapped on table list and i know i have done there wrong in case audio files implementation so please help me in this issues ,pleasure

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: showing exception like   error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.) and it's moving this block 
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

Comment: Check again... see the answer again...updated setttings!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90521/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-rumin).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not saving the captured images/photos and simply trying to use the paths. Please take a look at [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html) on how to use it. You can save them in your project's Documents directory, save the file name and path as you are doing then use those paths for rendering/playing later on.

As a side note, in your implementation, there are few lines of code that you are executing after `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]`. I would advise to utilize completion block here and load your table view once image picker view dismissal is complete. This avoid run time crashes.

**EDIT:** On OP request

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
    {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @“image1.png”];


        UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
       [imageData writeToFile: filePath atomically:YES];

      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        // Save your model data and reload table here 
       }];

    }
}
```

Comment: i am very begginer in ios can you please modified my code and post that

Comment: Sorry but I would encourage you to read the reference doc I shared the link for and learn. I gave you hint for your issue. You should be taking it from here.

Comment: how should i save them can you please explain

Comment: see my updates code images are displaying when i click tablelist rows but videos are not playing

Comment: I just updated my post with an example. Follow that.

Comment: where is your updated post

Comment: Looks like some network delay :). Check now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90511/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-abhinav).